# DynamicMapService on GoogleEarth?

Tags: dynamic-data, kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin, arcgis-server

can anyone tell me if it is possible to display an ArcGIS dynamicMapService on GoogleEarth via the GoogleMaps API? It works fine with KML but my services are only visible on the 2D maps.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

HI,

I got some help in the ESRI forum (thanks guys!) and what I they told me is that it is NOT possible to display an ArcGIS mapservice in the google-earth-plugin (=maptype: G_SATELLITE_3D_MAP) ! What should work is to allow the mapservice to have KML capability and then use the KML version instead.

Here some info on displaying mapservices as KML in ArcGIS Server environment.

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.2/dotNet/manager/publishing/kml_service.htm

best
Jens